# K&R - Exercise 1-9 - Removing Spaces

Tags: c, string, while-loop

I recently started learning C using the K&R book (2nd ed.) and I'm just having trouble wrapping my mind around this solution to exercise 1-9 which is:

> Write a program to copy its input to its output, replacing each string
>   of one or more blanks by a single blank.

I found the following solution online and it mostly makes sense except for that semi-colon above putchar(' ');. Without it the program doesn't perform its function properly, what function does that semi-colon serve?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int c;

  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if(c  == ' ') {
      while((c = getchar()) == ' ')
      ;
      putchar(' ');
    }
    putchar(c);
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't like that "solution", since it doesn't check for EOF in the innermost `getchar()`.

Comment: Note, code also has a flaw.  With input `" "` + `EOF`, code will call `putchar(' '); putchar(EOF);` when it only should call `putchar(' ');`  (I see this is hinted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45130206/kr-exercise-1-9-removing-spaces#comment77234920_45130206)).

Comment: K&R is *not* a good reference to learn the C language as it exists today, since it is no longer 1979, and many practices, recommendations and code samples in that book are simply incorrect or irrelevant

Answer (score 17):

The statement:

```
while((c = getchar()) == ' ')
;
```

is indented incorrectly. It should read:

```
while((c = getchar()) == ' ')
    ;
```

The `;` is an empty statement equivalent to an empty block `{ }`.

This lonely `;` is somewhat confusing, so it is considered good style to add a comment or some other emphasis to clarify its true nature:

```
while ((c = getchar()) == ' ') {
    /* nothing */
}

while ((c = getchar()) == ' ')
    /* nothing */;
```

Some bold programmers write this even more confusing form (avoid it):

```
while((c = getchar()) == ' ');
```

I personally prefer this equivalent form:

```
while ((c = getchar()) == ' ')
    continue;
```

Answer (score 12):

The statement

```
  while((c = getchar()) == ' ')
  ;
```

is parsed as

```
  while((c = getchar()) == ' ');
```

which has the same effect as

```
while((c = getchar()) == ' ') {
     /* Do nothing */
}
```

In other words, it's a while loop whose body has no effect. The act of checking the condition of the while loop reads characters and discards spaces, which is what you want to do.

If you delete the semicolon, then the while loop body ends up being the statement after the loop, which causes the wrong statement to repeat.

Comment: Maybe you should mention that it's atrocious style to use a simple semicolon without comment or anything as an empty statement, due to it being easily overlooked.